# Android how to run one small app in another

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have recently developed an app in which I wanna use a small app I have developed before, let's say in one view like below:

```
public class MyMain extends Activity {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    showmysmallapp(); //how?
  }
}
```

I have saved the small app as aar file and imported it to my new app and added in my `build.gradle` dependency also:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(":mysmallapp")
  ... 
}
```

How can I run the entire small app when a view of my main app starts pls?

or should I have added the library in another way?

Much thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to run an app as a plugin.

You can use one of these libraries:

1. [VirtualApp](https://github.com/asLody/VirtualApp)

   > VirtualApp is an open platform for Android that allows you to create a
   >   Virtual Space, you can install and run apk inside. Beyond that,
   >   VirtualApp is also a Plugin Framework, the plugins running on
   >   VirtualApp does not require any constraints. VirtualApp does not
   >   require root, it is running on the local process
2. [DL: Apk](https://github.com/singwhatiwanna/dynamic-load-apk) (Readme in chinese).
3. [Android PluginManager](https://github.com/houkx/android-pluginmgr)

   > PluginManager is used to manage android applications like eclipse
   >   plugins. you can start an activity from an uninstalled apk placed in
   >   sdcard,just like it has installed or registed in the application's
   >   AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i just figured it out, all i needed was

Comment: Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mysmallapp.labs");
        if (launchIntent != null) {
            startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
        } inside the main app view

Comment: But now with the above code, the smallapp opens in a different app, any idea to run it at the same app?